# What is the default highlight color of a menu in C#?

Tags: c#, colors, highlight

I can't seem to find out the exact color to the highlight when hovering over menu options in C#, anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: C# is a programming language, not a program or an application. You need to be more specific. Why not post a screen shot?

Comment: Take a screenshot and read the color using your favorite image editing program??

Comment: Remember that system colours may change according to themes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but there is a property: `SystemColors.MenuHighlight` if you want to match the system colors in your own GUI?

Comment: This is the best route, as the color is completely dependent on the user's theme.

Comment: Does anybody know what this color is in hex, for CSS? I'm not writing in C# or anything, just html/css, so I don't know how to access SystemColors.MenuHighlight.

Comment: @fronzee It depends on the user's system settings, I'm not sure of anyway to do this from Javascript, sorry